# HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am doing an assignment project of PostgreSQL about implementing similarity joins. I followed the experiment guide to modify code in the PostgreSQL installation package. The following is the relevant part:

> In the file `"src/backend/utils/fmgr/funcapi.c"` add the following two
> functions:
> And the main work of this project(Part I) is to implement these two
> functions:

```sql
Datum levenshtein_distance(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    text *str_01 = PG_GETARG_DATUM(0);
    text *txt_02 = PG_GETARG_DATUM(1);
    int32 result=1;
    PG_RETURN_INT32(result);
}
Datum jaccard_index (PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    text *str_01 = PG_GETARG_DATUM(0);
    text *txt_02 = PG_GETARG_DATUM(1);
    float4 result=1;
    PG_RETURN_FLOAT4(result);
}
```

> In the file `"src/include/catalog/pg_proc.h"` add the following two sentences:

```sql
DATA(insert OID = 4375 ( levenshtein_distance PGNSP PGUID 12 1 0 0 f f f t f i 2 0 20 "25 25" _null_ _null_ _null_ _null_ levenshtein_distance _null_ _null_ _null_));
DESCR("levenshtein_distance");
DATA(insert OID = 4376 ( jaccard_index PGNSP PGUID 12 1 0 0 f f f t f i 2 0 700 "25 25" _null_ _null_ _null_ _null_ jaccard_index _null_ _null_ _null_));
DESCR("jaccard_index");
```

> Use the following command to rebuild and install a modified
> version of postgres that uses your new modified code:

```
make
make install
```

After doing all things listed above, I tried using levenshtein function:

```sql
similarity2=# select levenshtein_distance('sunday','sanday');
ERROR:  function levenshtein_distance(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select levenshtein_distance('sunday','sanday');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Does anyone know how this error raised? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `levenshtein` function is part of the extension fuzzystrmatch. Make sure you have that installed. In your Postgres run `create extension fuzzystrmatch;`

Comment: @Belayer Yeah probably there's extension package containing levenshtein function, but this assignment requires me to implement this function manually from scratch...

Comment: If I am following the function name is `levenshtein_distance` not `levenshtein`. So should it not be `select levenshtein_distance('sunday','sanday')`?

Comment: Did you `initdb` after `make install`? Did you modify the catalog version?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Oops, thanks! Yeah, it was a typo and I've corrected it now. But the query still yields the same error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The project guide tells me that it's not necessary to ```initdb``` again. Is it necessary actually?

Comment: Well, when do you think will these functions you added to `pg_proc.h` be created?